# Vue conditional style tag in single file component

Tags: css, vue.js, web-component

I have started development on a vue web component library. Members of my team asked for the potential to remove default styles via an HTML attribute on the web component. I know that I could use CSS class bindings on the template elements, however, I was wondering if there is a way to conditionally include the style tag itself so that I would not need to change the class names in order to include the base styles or not.

Example of a component's structure

```
    <template>
      <section class="default-class" />
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      props: {
        useDefault: Boolean
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    <style>
      // Default styles included here
      // Ideally the style tag or it's content could be included based off useDefault prop
    </style>
```

Potential implementation

```
    <web-component use-default="false"></web-component>
```

Comment: No. You cannot conditionally load the style tag within an SFC.

Comment: You may use this new feature [State-Driven Dynamic CSS](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#state-driven-dynamic-css).

Comment: Try this:       <section :class="default-class: useDefault" />

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question; you want to keep `<style>` both affecting Global DOM *and* shadowDOM

One way is to **clone** those `<style>` elements into shadowDOM

But maybe `::parts` works better for you; see: https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/

```js
customElements.define("web-component", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
      .innerHTML = "<div>Inside Web Component</div>";
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    // get all styles from global DOM and clone them inside the Web Component
    let includeStyles = this.getAttribute("clone-styles");
    let globalStyles = document.querySelectorAll(`[${includeStyles}]`);
    let clonedStyles = [...globalStyles].map(style => style.cloneNode(true));
    this.shadowRoot.prepend(...clonedStyles);
  }
});
```

```html
<style mystyles>
  div {
    background: gold
  }
</style>
<style mystyles>
  div {
    color: blue
  }
</style>

<div>I am Global</div>
<web-component clone-styles="mystyles"></web-component>
```